# Limit using theorem of monotone convergence and without L'Hopital rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Prove using theorem of monotone convergence that limit below converges, in other words, prove analytically that limit below converges:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{5^x}{2^{x^2}}$$

I tried doing: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x \cdot \ln{5}}{x^2\cdot \ln{2}}=0$$ but I don't know if this is allowed by the theorem.

Comment: I suppose you mean the denominator is $2^{x^2}$?

Comment: Yupp, please for an idea

Comment: Eventually $2^x>5$.

Comment: So you're trying to argue that if $f(x),g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\log f(x)}{\log g(x)} = 0$, then presumably $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$. This is actually correct, but can you justify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Rewrite $5^x$ as $2^{x\log_2 5}$, so that
$$\frac{5^x}{2^{x^2}}=2^{x\log_25-x^2}$$
(You don't really need the monotone convergence theorem, only the continuity ot the function $t\mapsto 2^t$.)

*Some more details*:

As a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term, $\;\lim_{x\to +\infty}(x\log_25-x^2)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}(-x^2)=-\infty$, so
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{5^x}{2^{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}2^{x\log_25-x^2}=\lim_{u\to -\infty}2^u=0.$$

Comment: But what does this prove? As I see, after x=3, nuber inside of logarithm will be negative, and how can that be continuity?

Comment: Can you find the limit of the exponent?

Comment: No, plus I can't since it has minus sign in between, so I can't extract $x^2$. And why would I do than when I already found limit of it? How do I use this theorem?

Comment: Don't forget a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term. ‘How do I use’ which theorem exactly do you mean?

Comment: Do you mind filling in the rest?

Comment: Done! Is that clear?

Comment: Yupp, thanks, your's is the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

We could try the following:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac5{2^x}=0$$

so there's $\;M\in\Bbb R^+\;$ such that $\;x>M\implies \cfrac5{2^x}\le q<1\;$ , and thus

$$\lim_{x\to\infty\\x>M}\frac{5^x}{2^{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty\\x>M}\left(\frac 5{2^x}\right)^x\le\lim_{x\to\infty\\x>M} q^x=0$$

Fill in details in the above.

Comment: $2^x$ isn't the same as $2^{x^x}$

Comment: @dzaralica69 Of course not...but $\;2^{x^2}=2^{x\cdot x}=\left(2^x\right)^x\;$ **is** ... and on this the whole idea of the above proof rests.

Comment: I still don't understand the part with q and M

Comment: Do you understand what is written up to "and thus" ? This will allow the basic next step! If you don't understand that then I can't help you.